# Sharepoint Online and IdentityServer4

Tags: azure, sharepoint

One of my clients has a SharePoint online environment. We want to implement and integrate IdentityServer4 to support an additional user store. We want to use this to store external user accounts. We also want to create a Single Signon situation.

The question is what options exist to integrate the SharePoint Online Azure Active Directory with the IdentityServer4 product.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain in a bit more detail what you are looking to achieve here? Is your question, can you secure SharePoint Online with Identity Server 4? Or are you looking to secure other applications using the same Azure Active Directory accounts that are used to access your SharePoint instance? E.g. Azure Active Directory accounts?

Comment: The main purpose is to be able to add users in such a way that they can use the environment, however we do not want to use the active directory for storing those accounts.

Comment: OK - so basically, you want users to sign into SharePoint online, but you do not want the user store to be Azure Active Directory? You want to use a custom user store with authentication provided by Identity Server?

Comment: Thats it!, the question is, can it be done?

Comment: A brief look through the article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-federation-compatibility suggests that using 3rd party identity providers for sign in to Office 365 solutions (such as SharePoint online) is indeed supported.  The link doesn't provide any implementation details, but does perhaps confirm that this should be possible if you want to look at this in further detail.